# How to flatten large loop stacks?

Tags: python, loops, iteration

Let's say I wanted to get all the possible combinations of three binary digits, i.e:

```
0,0,0
0,0,1
0,1,0
0,1,1
1,0,0
1,0,1
1,1,0
1,1,1
```

I could do something like this:

```
p = []
for a in range(2):
    for b in range(2):
        for c in range(2):
           p.append([a,b,c])

print p
```

But what if I wanted to define a function that returns the possiblities for n numbers of binary digits? i.e. How can I stack the for loops dynamically?

Comment: use `itertools.product`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
from itertools import product
product(range(2), repeat=3)
```

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [`itertools.product`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.product).

Answer (score 2):

No `itertools` solution.

```
def binarydigits(n):
    if n == 1:
        yield (0,)
        yield (1,)
    else:
        for i in binarydigits(n-1):
            for j in binarydigits(1):
                yield i+j
```

Comment: In general, I would prefer an `itertools`-based solution to a recursive generator.

Comment: For fun: `bd = lambda n: iter(((0,),(1,))) if n == 1 else (i+j for i in bd(n-1) for j in bd(1))`. (I like to write recursive lambdas even though they aren't practical, don't ask me why).

Answer (score 2):

You really only need one loop for your specific case, since the sequence of 0s and 1s you want represents successive integers:

```
def allbinary(ndigits):
    for n in xrange(2 ** ndigits):
        yield map(int, bin(n)[2:].zfill(ndigits))

for x in allbinary(8): print x
```

Note that `map()` produces a list rather than a tuple, but you could just convert it to a tuple if you need that specifically.

However, `itertools.product` as recommended by others is a better solution in most cases, including this one.